# Descobrir qual coluna seria truncada (data would be truncated)

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

boa noite! Ao tentar inserir um registro no SQLServer através da minha aplicação estou recebendo uma mensagem de dado truncado. O problema é que são muitas as colunas que essa tela preenche e não tenho ideia de qual está sendo truncada. Existe alguma forma de saber qual coluna / tabela está provocando o erro?

> ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(101) | String or binary data
>   would be truncated.

Comment: Sugiro que altere o aplicativo para retornar as demais informações de erro que são fornecidas pelo SQL Server. Além de ERROR_MESSAGE(), há também ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE() e outros.

Comment: Se você alterar seu aplicativo limitando a quantidade de caracteres que o usuário pode digitar em cada campo de acordo com a capacidade de cada coluna, você resolve seu problema de uma vez por todas.

Answer (score 1):

Dos muitos pedidos à equipa responsável pelo MS SQL Server por parte da comunidade de utilizadores, este deve estar no topo da lista. Fica aqui apenas um exemplo:

[Please fix the "String or binary data would be truncated" message to give the column name](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/)

Se deparar com o erro em ambiente de produção é bastante complicado detectar qual é a coluna responsável pelo erro, pois os dados em muitos casos são provenientes da camada de UI.

Em ambiente de desenvolvimento/testes, ou se estiver por exemplo a carregar a informação proveniente de um ficheiro, existem algumas alternativas, uma das quais é aceder à informação disponível na tabela sys.columns e comparar, coluna a coluna, com a informação que está a tentar inserir na tabela.

Uma vez que está a executar um insert, assumo que de alguma forma já mapeou a informação entre a origem dos dados e a tabela de destino.

Comece por criar uma tabela temporária com os dados que pretende inserir, é importante que os nomes das colunas sejam iguais aos da tabela na qual pretende inserir.

Neste exemplo vamos assumir que pretende inserir a informação na tabela TabelaXPTO e que esta tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE TabelaXPTO
(
   Coluna1     NVARCHAR(250),
   Coluna2     NVARCHAR(250),
   Coluna3     NVARCHAR(250),
   Coluna4     NVARCHAR(250),
   Coluna5     NVARCHAR(250),
)


SELECT X1 AS Coluna1
      ,X2 AS Coluna2
      ,X3 AS Coluna3
      ,X4 AS Coluna4
      ,X5 AS Coluna5  
  INTO #TabelaTemporaria
  FROM Origem
```

Agora, usando a informação na tabela sys.columns, pode comparar as duas tabelas (tabela temporária e tabela de destino):

```
SELECT 
WITH Destino AS 
(
    SELECT C.column_id ,
           ColumnName= C.name ,
           C.max_length ,
           C.user_type_id ,
           C.precision ,
           C.scale ,
           DataTypeName = T.name
      FROM sys.columns C
     INNER JOIN sys.types T 
        ON T.user_type_id = C.user_type_id
     WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('TabelaXPTO')
),
DadosOrigem AS 
(
    SELECT C.column_id ,
           ColumnName= C.name ,
           C.max_length ,
           C.user_type_id ,
           C.precision ,
           C.scale ,
           DataTypeName = T.name
      FROM TempDB.sys.columns C
      INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.types T 
         ON T.user_type_id=C.user_type_id
      INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.objects O 
         ON o.object_id=c.object_id
      WHERE O.name = 'TabelaTemporaria'
)
SELECT * 
  FROM Destino D
  INNER JOIN DadosOrigem O 
    ON D.ColumnName = O.ColumnName
WHERE ISNULL(D.max_length,0) < ISNULL(O.max_length,999)  --> O tamanho da coluna na tabela de destino é inferir ao tamanho dos dados que pretende inserir.
```

É possível que tenha que fazer alguns ajustes no código em cima, uma vez que de momento não estou num computador com SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Abre o Sql Server provider, pega a query e abre no sql manager e tenta executar no interativo. Lá ele te da a linha que deu erro.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho 50 pontos para comentar diretamente na resposta do Bruno, mas para funcionar na minha situação eu tive que usar o WHERE O.name like '#tempCalib%' porque havia uma série de caracteres acrescentados pelo SQL após o nome da tabela impedindo o = de funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).